# How can we show the following matrix is positive semidefinite or not

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-semidefinite

Suppose $U$ is $m \times n$ and $rank(U) = n$. Also, that $A$ is $m \times m$ and is invertible. How can I show whether the following difference is positive semidefinite or not?

$$U(U^\top A U)^{-1}U^\top - A^{-1}.$$

I tried to factorize this difference, but couldn't.

Comment: $U^TAU$ may not even be invertible...
But supposing it is, consider the signs and relative size of the eigenvalues of $A^{-1}$ and of $A^{-1}$ multiplied by a bunch of stuff

Comment: @WyattKuehster: Yes, I assume $U^\top A U$ is invertible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One sufficient condition is that $A\prec 0$. In this case, let $B=-A$ and $V=B^{1/2}U$. Then
\begin{aligned}
&U(U^\top AU)^{-1}U^\top-A^{-1}\succeq0\\
&\Leftrightarrow B^{-1}-U(U^\top BU)^{-1}U^\top\succeq0\\
&\Leftrightarrow B^{1/2}\left(B^{-1}-U(U^\top BU)^{-1}U^\top\right)B^{1/2}\succeq0\\
&\Leftrightarrow I-V(V^\top V)^{-1}V^\top\succeq0,
\end{aligned}
which is true because $I-V(V^\top V)^{-1}V^\top$ is the orthogonal projection onto the orthogonal complement of the column space of $V$.

Comment: How did you write the 3rd equation from the 2nd?

Comment: Thanks. If we assume $A$ is positive definite, then it means this difference is negative definite, right?

Comment: @shani If $A$ is PD, the difference is negative semidefinite. Unless $U=0$, it can never be negative definite, because $\left(U(U^\top AU)^{-1}U^\top-A^{-1}\right)AU=0$

Comment: I don't quite understand the justification you have given at the end. Could you please explain why you have considered $(U(U^\top AU)^{-1}U^\top - A^{-1})AU$?

Comment: @shani A matrix cannot be definite if it is singular.

Comment: Thanks. I got it.

Comment: Is still there a typo in the 3rd equation? Because I can't derive it from the second.

Comment: Ok. Probably I have got it wrong. Did you simply multiply both sides of the 2nd equation by $B^{1/2}$? I thought you are trying to take $B^{1/2}$ out from the 2nd equation.

Comment: @shani Yes, I multiply both sides by $B^{1/2}$. Since positive semidefiniteness is preserved by [matrix congruence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_congruence), the third line is equivalent to the second one.

Answer (score 2):

Consider $U:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^m$. Since $U$ is rank $n$, we know that $\mathbb R^m=V\oplus W$, where $\dim_\mathbb RV=m$. So that $U^T|_{V}$ is invertible. The assumption that $U^TAU$ is invertible means that $A(V)=V$.

Consider now $a\in V$ and $b\in W$, so that $a+b$ is an arbitrary $m$-vector. Then one can see that
$$
(U(U^TAU)^{-1}U^T-A^{-1})(a+b) = -A^{-1}b.
$$
So you need $A$ to be negative semi-definite on the space $W$.